# I want to give the user a specified message but my program gives the user all the messages in java

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, joptionpane

in my program the user enters a number and the method below calculates the number and gives the user a message based on the number they entered, however I use an if statement to calculate what message to give on the number but when the user enters the number it displays all the messages, the numbers are in sets of 10 which means if the user entered a number from 40 to 49 then it would output the E grade message, can someone tell me how it can be made so that it only gives me the message for the specified numbers it is compared against?

```
public void checkInputScore() {

    if (convertedInputScore == -1) {
        System.exit(0);
    } 

    if (convertedInputScore < 39) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received a fail grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);            
    }

    if (convertedInputScore <= 49) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received an E grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    if (convertedInputScore <= 59) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received an D grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `else if` statement.

```
if (convertedInputScore == -1) {
    System.exit(0);
} else if (convertedInputScore < 39) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received a fail grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);            
} else if (convertedInputScore <= 49) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received an E grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} else if (convertedInputScore <= 59) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received an D grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vulcan, please see the [FAQ on the `homework` tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) when answering future `homework` tagged questions.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks for helping out, but I know how it works.  I mistakenly didn't notice it was homework until I visited the question after my answer was marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (convertedInputScore == -1) {
   System.exit(0);
}
```

use some elses:

```
 if (convertedInputScore < 39) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received a fail grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);            
} else if (convertedInputScore <= 49) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received an E grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} else  if (convertedInputScore <= 59) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Program1.this, "The student received an D grade", "Student mark checker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

A number that is less than 39, is also going to be less than 49; and since every check after the first `if` is true, your program displays all the messages.

This should help you in solving your homework problem.